# How to Prevent Jquery UI dragSelect when any modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

I need open a modal on a page where JQuery UI dragSelect is implemented
I want to stop dragSelect when the modal is visible when I click on modal items are selecting in the background.

searched in the documentation of dragSelect but couldn't find anything

Comment: https://codepen.io/_hardik143/pen/vYzyRwv
here's the codepen for the above code

Answer (score 0):

worked with this

```
// removed selectables when mouse enters modal and do the opposites of it
$(document).on('mouseenter click','.modal',function(){
  ds.removeSelectables($('.item'))
})
$(document).on('mouseleave','.modal',function(){
  ds.removeSelectables($('.item'))
})
```